# Is it possible to define a discriminated union in a SHACL schema?

Tags: rdf, json-ld, shacl

Is it possible to define a discriminated union in a SHACL schema?

Here is a contrived example; I only want to enforce the `minCount: 1` constraint on the `ex:tail` property if the `ex:type` property has the value `Dog`.

```
ex:Animal a <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class>, sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path ex:type ;
        sh:maxCount 1 ;
        sh:minCount 1 ;
        sh:in ("Dog" "Frog") ;
    ],[
        sh:path ex:tail ;
        sh:in ("Fluffy" "Long") ;
        sh:maxCount 1 ;
        sh:minCount 1 ;
        sh:condition [
            sh:property [
                sh:path ex:type ;
                sh:hasValue "Dog" ;
            ]
        ];
    ].
```

The above example doesn't work and is intended to be illustrative only. Is there a way to define these conditional constraints in SHACL?

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this is to reformulate the condition into a "not [precondition] sh:or [constraint]". In your case, "either type is not dog or sh:property tail".

I have not tested the code below but maybe this is a starting point:

```
ex:Animal 
    a rdfs:Class, sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:property ex:Animal-type ;
    sh:or (
        [
            sh:not [
                sh:property [
                    sh:path ex:type ;
                    sh:hasValue "dog" ;
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [
            sh:property ex:Animal-tail ;
        ]
    )
.
ex:Animal-type
    a sh:PropertyShape ;
    sh:path ex:type ;
    sh:maxCount 1 ;
    sh:minCount 1 ;
    sh:in ("Dog" "Frog") ;
.
ex:Animal-tail
    a sh:PropertyShape ;
    sh:path ex:tail ;
    sh:in ("Fluffy" "Long") ;
    sh:maxCount 1 ;
    sh:minCount 1 ;
.
```